# \d command doesnt work anymore with psql-client 8.3 (upgrade to v9.0)

Tags: postgresql, psql

Since we upgrade our postgresql 8.3 to postgresql 9, \d command doesnt works anymore with psql-client 8.3 :

`ERROR:  column "reltriggers" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT relhasindex, relkind, relchecks, reltriggers, relhasr"`

In postgres trees psql-client must download as one package with postgresql9. Where i can download *only psql-client binary package* a.k.a psql for Postgresql 9.0 ?

Update:
This case occur when older psql-client trying to access a newer version of postgres (psql-client: 8.3 trying to access postgres-server: 9.0).

Comment: You're trying to use an old client with a new server. As Peter has hinted you need to upgrade the client but that's (arguably) OS-dependent.

Comment: Peter, Sorry forgot that : Ubuntu 9.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that Ubuntu does not ship PostgreSQL 9.0 yet.  So this could be a bit tricky.  Either you build PostgreSQL 9.0 from source and only install the client parts that you want, or you download the Debian source package for postgresql-9.0 and build that on Ubuntu and then only install the postgresql-client-9.0 package.

Or you install the postgresql-client-8.4 package.  This isn't quite the solution, but it's closer to it, and I verified that it will get you past the error you showed.